# Changing Background Color in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript

I want to change the background color in a Flash document while the time is bigger than 100. I already created a counter and assigned it as a movieclip. My current code is:

```
time--;

//this is for motion tween

if (time>0) {
    gotoAndPlay(2);
}   

if (time == 0) {
    fscommand("quit");
    stop();
}
```

I tried to add

```
if (time>100) {setStyle("backgroundColor", #FFFFFF);}
```

but it didn't work.

Can you give any clue to solve this problem?

Comment: What is setStyle? a function? Are you sure that it even enters in if (time>100) statement?

Answer (score 3):

100 seconds? And you have movieclip with second frame with desired color I assume. So, Code in first frame will be:

```
setTimeout(function () : void {
    myMovieClipName.gotoAndStop(2);
}, 100000); // 100 * 1000 ms
```

where myMovieClipName is name of your movieclip, give it name at stage.

Comment: This is bad really practice. Using an entire MovieClip just to change the stage colour is really inefficient when one line of code will do the job, and setTimeout is deprecated in as3, you ought to use the Timer class instead.

Comment: Also, it's kind of odd how you've only answered one question, very badly, and gotten all your rep (four up-votes) for it in the space of a few hours. I like your site though!

Comment: @Nicolas Siver, Actually it is difficult for me to explain the details of the code (since I am only a novice and do something intuitively). But, I guess setTimeout may not be used because I try to exit from the swf file (you can think it as a question) when it is done, not from the movieclip :s.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what setStyle is, if it's a function of your own can you post the method body for us? It'll be wrong in any case as AS3 won't recognise number beginning with the hash symbol, you need to start hexadecimal numbers with 0x (see below)

Anyway, supposing it's an assumed native function which doesn't actually exist, to change the stage (ie Flash), use:

```
stage.color = 0xFFFFFF;
```

To change the background of an HTML page it's embedded in, call:

```
ExternalInterface.call("ELEMENT.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff'; ");
```

...where ELEMENT is a reference to the element you wish to change i.e body, a div etc

In any case, your conditional logic is confusing, if the above doesn't help can you post more of your code so we can see what's actually happening? Thanks.

**EDIT**

This isn't how I'd write such an application, but in order to fit in with your existing code  this condition will work (provided you are coding on the root timeline):

```
if(time < 10)
{
     stage.color = 0xFF0000;
}
```

Comment: Hi Lante! Thanks for the reply. But I cannot implement it.
I tried to write:
if (time == 100) { 
x.color = 0xFFFFFF; }
but it didn't work again.

I have not more code:) I have only a stage than 3 buttons (like in a question). When 10 seconds left, the stage should change its color from dark to light.

Comment: What is 'x'? You can't set .color on an object unless it has that property - the stage does, but MovieClips etc don't. Can you explain exactly what you want to achieve? Don't worry about showing your code, just explain the concept and I'll try and help you.

Comment: I will try to explain it. 
I am preparing a multiple choice question. There are one graphic item at the top of the scene and three buttons at above. People have restricted time to answer. I created a timer and wrote time = 120; for the first frame and the above code 
time--;

if (time>0) {
 gotoAndPlay(2);
} 



if (time == 0) {
 fscommand("quit");
 stop();
}

for the 13th frame. _I want to change the background color while timer shows "10 seconds left"_.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show what you need to do with your current code...in future you might want to look into using the Timer (just ask if you want to know how and I'll show you), it's neater than ENTER_FRAME

Comment: Are you coding on the root timeline? Can you post your complete code for me, I'll see what I can do...

Comment: Thanks again. No, not in the root timeline. Actually, my timer is a movieclip and I have no more codes than before. If you accept, I can send you the file?

Comment: Ah - you're using AS2. Probably best to specify this in tags as it's pretty much obsolete - move to as3 as soon as you can! I haven't touched as2 in about five years, but when I get out of work I'll have a look at it for you

Comment: Thanks for the comments :-) I will try to move to as3.